# Is doubly encrypting data less secure?

Tags: security, encryption

I remember hearing at some point this idea that if you encrypt data *twice*, it stands a chance of actually being *less* secure as encrypting only once. I am trying to figure out if there is any substantial reasoning behind this.

Intuitively, encrypting twice using different keys means effectively doubling your key strength. Is this not a valid intuition?

I can imagine *worst case scenarios* where the final data is actually "closer" to the original by essentially random chance, but this doesn't make the data any less secure, as hackers would be wasting their effort to rely on that outrageously small chance.

Comment: I am talking about keyed encryption schemes, using different keys for each stage of encryption obviously.

Comment: ROT(6, ROT(7, ROT(13, plaintext)))

Comment: This sounds like a joke, but the lesson is that you don't use intuition when it comes to encryption. Use a well known cipher with a large enough key and a good protocol with integrity/authenticity. And yes, that known good cipher *can* be 3DES (for lecacy applications, AES is definitely better).

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting twice may improve your security but not nearly as much as you might suspect.

[Diffie and Hellman discovered in 1977](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) that there is a time-space tradeoff possible that allows for cracking a doubly-encrypted content in O(2^(N+1)) time, rather than the O(2^(2N)) time that you were probably expecting. It does require O(2^n) *space* to contain partially-computed results, which can be expensive, but the gist is that you've essentially added roughly *one bit* to the encrypting key.

[TripleDES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) is usually done with two independent keys in an Encrypt, Decrypt, Encrypt fashion. (Three independent keys is possible but rare.)

Comment: TripleDES is currently considered unsecure as it has been proven repeatedly encrypting does not add obfuscation.  This is why a single key AES is now the standard.

Comment: Really? I was under the impression that for ciphers where the cipher didn't form a group under repeated application, repeated encryption helped matters a little. I'd definitely never suggest TripleDES for _new_ applications, as single-key AES is stronger, faster, and easier to implement. I just refer to its decision that double-encryption isn't nearly worth any effort.

Comment: DES is one of ciphers which are PROVEN to have greater strength with multiple encryption: "DES is not a group", http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2230. TripleDES is considered insecure due to advances in attacks and hardware, not because it's basically flawed.

Answer (score 2):

It will not hurt to encrypt your data with two DIFFERENT keys and good cipher: in worst case you will have at least same security as with single encryption.

Encrypting twice with SAME key is completely different. For XOR-based stream cipher it will produce original plaintext: P xor K xor K = P, no matter how good is keystream K. Never do it.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the context. check this article, i think it have some answers for you : [Well, is encrypting twice much more secure?](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/sci.crypt/2010-01/msg00272.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it made sense at all that encrypting twice with different keys would make it easier to crack than the first step of an attack could just be for the attacker to encrypt it them self. In the case that it does help to do this than you didn't do anything that the attacker couldn't do them self in a short amount of time.

Of course this does not mean that it is worth doing, just that it cant hurt assuming that you are using different keys.

Answer (score 0):

No, simply consider that by encrypting something a second time it is just as secure as it is with one encryption.

This is because of something called the meet in the middle attack which prevents the need to brute force the entire thing.

If you encrypt the data one way and store the results then decrypt the other way and cross reference the results then you can very easily find both encryption keys separately.

It's no less secure, no more secure. Simply bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

Strong encryption is based on moding your data from the combination of two very large prime numbers.  To repeat this process could produce data which was the combination of many different possibilities as opposed to the two large, hard to find, prime factors.

Comment: I see the reasoning, but it is not logical. You still had to travel *through* the first encryption. Using a completely arbitrary encryption a second time has no chance of regressing the first one. Or am I missing something. To simplify, yea adding two signed numbers instead of one could theoretically put you back where you started. But you have no way of knowing IF that was the starting point. The entropy introduced in the first encryption is not reversed by the second.

Comment: This is incorrect, you do not have to unlock one to unlock the other.  You simply are going to be unlocking the union of the two encryptions, which will be easier than unlocking either one of them because the encryption will NO LONGER be based off of a prime number encryption.  Might as well just take your data, foreach() data.value += 1; and then store it because that is the same thing that you are doing when removing the abstraction of the prime factors.

Comment: Note that the original question from tenfour doesn't mention RSA.

Comment: Sorry, but repeating encryption is not done and is seen as unsecure.  Maybe this was good in the 80s...

Comment: Actually, strong encryption do not require any prime numbers. Public key encryption using some algorithms requires them, symmetric encryption do not. Both can be strong or weak.